# UIKit - Using Plist to retrive image

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit, key, plist

I'm banging my head over here.

**Target**

Creating plist that contains image keys. Loading and image by key name - on **UIKit**

**What i have tried so far :**

Plist sample :

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>frames</key>
    <dict>
        <key>flowerpattern_0.jpg</key>
        <dict>
            <key>frame</key>
            <string>{{2,2},{100,100}}</string>
            <key>offset</key>
            <string>{0,0}</string>
            <key>rotated</key>
            <false/>
            <key>sourceColorRect</key>
            <string>{{0,0},{100,100}}</string>
            <key>sourceSize</key>
            <string>{100,100}</string>
        </dict>


    </dict>
    <key>metadata</key>
    <dict>
        <key>format</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>realTextureFileName</key>
        <string>flower_pattern_plist.jpg</string>
        <key>size</key>
        <string>{1022,104}</string>
        <key>smartupdate</key>
        <string>$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:2e0802c1c0d11825873827deec34bf23:622a62cd100e0ea2e4b15f2b6ecde20c:f7e873e0cfa3c1fd5648760bfa48db16$</string>
        <key>textureFileName</key>
        <string>flower_pattern_plist.jpg</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**How i tried getting the image out :**

```
var myDict : NSDictionary?
var temp = String()
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("flower_pattern_plist", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
if let dict = myDict {
    let image: AnyObject? = dict["frames"]!
    println(image)
    temp = image!.allKeys[0] as! String
}
 self.CollageChild.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: temp)!)
```

but so far it fails , any suggestions? is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads the file wrong. First of all, you can either define `frames` as an array (not dictionary) and use `AnyObject`, or you can use `frames["flowerpattern_0"]`. I would suggest the array option...

Next, add a `fileName` key to the object in the .plist file:

```
<key>frames</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>fileName</key>
        <string>flowerpattern_0.jpg</string>
        //your other stuff...
    </dict>
</array>
```

And getting your image like this:

```
var imageName = image!.valueForKey("fileName") as! String
var finalImage = UIImage(named : imageName)
```